# On Click on the RowHeader the current row should be editable and On click of the columnHearder current column of all row should be editable

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, datagrid

I have a silverlight DataGrid, by default on page load the all the cells of the datagrid should be Readonly. I have 2 problem , can any one help me?

1.On Click on the RowHeader the current row should be editable 
2. On click of the columnHearder current column of all row should be editable

Comment: can you post more details and some sample xaml code of of what you have currently or have tried?

Comment: Hi Stainedart,
My requirement is like there is DataGrid Control ,when I click the any column header then all the cells below the column should be editable so that I can change the current value to new value
like that for the Row Header.


I think DataGrid  does not provide these functionality by default.
So currnetly I created custom controll and fulfilled my requirement.

but still Any suggestion heartly invited :)

Answer (score 0):

This might not solve your entire problem but it should partially address it.

This is to make a column read-only in a datagrid

```
DataGrid.Columns[7].IsReadOnly = true;
```

Obviously the property can be changed from events but the data grid does not have row/column headers event handlers. Custom controls seem the way to go without introducing any new gui elements like buttons and changing the feel of the application.